# Visible thin white slits between elements in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm creating a pixel art editor application with Android Studio using Kotlin. And - for this - I've decided to create a RecyclerView with a grid layout adapter which contains a custom View called a Pixel.

Whenever a Pixel is pressed, the colour turns black.

Here is the code:

Canvas Fragment:

```
package com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.databinding.FragmentCanvasBinding

class CanvasFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentCanvasBinding? = null

    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private lateinit var caller: CanvasFragmentListener

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): CanvasFragment {
            return CanvasFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        if (context is CanvasFragmentListener) {
            caller = context
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCanvasBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        setUpRecyclerView()

        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView() {
        val context = activity as Context
        binding.canvasRecyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 25)
        val pixels = caller.initPixels()
        binding.canvasRecyclerView.adapter = CanvasRecyclerAdapter(pixels, caller)
        binding.canvasRecyclerView.suppressLayout(true)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Recycler Adapter:

```
class CanvasRecyclerAdapter(private val pixels: List<Pixel>,
                            private val caller: CanvasFragmentListener) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerViewHolder {
        return RecyclerViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentPixel = pixels[position]
        holder.tileParent.addView(currentPixel)

        holder.tileParent.setOnClickListener {
            caller.onPixelTapped(currentPixel)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = pixels.size
}
```

And ViewHolder:

```
class RecyclerViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup)
    : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.pixel_layout, parent, false)) {
    val tileParent: SquareFrameLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pixelParent)
}
```

Canvas Activity:

```
class CanvasActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CanvasFragmentListener {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityCanvasBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setBindings()
        setUpFragment()
    }

    private fun setUpFragment() {
        supportFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentHost, CanvasFragment.newInstance()).commit()
    }

    private fun setBindings() {
        binding = ActivityCanvasBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    override fun initPixels(): List<Pixel> {
        val list = mutableListOf<Pixel>()
        for (i in 1..625) {
            list.add(Pixel(this))
        }
        return list.toList();
    }

    override fun onPixelTapped(pixel: Pixel) {
        pixel.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
    }
}
```

Pixel:

```
class Pixel : View {
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributes: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributes)

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val width = measuredWidth
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width)
    }
}
```

XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CanvasFragment"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentHost">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/canvasRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Now, I understand this **may not be the best approach for this**, but that is besides the point.

The point is that when I run the app I get these visible thin white slits between each pixel:

[image]

Sometimes only one column has the issue:

[image]

In fact most of the time it's one column that does and another that doesn't:

[image]

Regardless of the grid size, I still see this visible annoyance.

**Now, I am not sure if it's a rendering issue with my EMU - but it doesn't seem to be the case.**

---

This is NOT an EMU issue, my friend installed the APK and sent a screenshot of his phone and it was still visible:

(Picture of friend's phone.)

[image]

Comment: "a RecyclerView with a grid layout adapter which contains a custom View called a Pixel." -> very creative solution :)

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thank you. It's creative but it's overall a poor solution, I would have preferred using a Canvas but due to my limited knowledge I can't just yet. Do you have any solution to my problem?

Comment: I do believe that this is some rounding problem, as you are setting 25x25 `Pixel` grid, but you are drawing it on some `View` which may take literally any width... so e.g. 480/25 is 19.2 width/height of pixel. then some pixels are drawn with 19px edge, others with 20...

Comment: Yeah, probably a rounding issue in GridLayoutManager. It maybe hasn't been tested for views having fully opaque backgrounds since that is unusual. Canvas would be sooooooooo much easier.

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you know any good books/resources in which I can learn Canvas for pixel art? Cheers.

Comment: I don't. I learned it from reading the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing) and reading the source code of various views in Android to see how it works. You could also check Github for open source custom views to see how they work.

Comment: I don't agree with either statement that @Tenfour04 issued. Direct `canvas` manipulation is not "much easier" at all, and it would introduce extra responsibilities. I also don't think the view opacity has anything to do with GridLayout repsonsibilities (and as such, that it "wasn't tested"). If you're overriding a core framework method (onMeasure) then *you* now have the responsibility to correctly measure your views, and not the LayoutManager which doesn't measure views, just lays them down on the screen based on its own logic.

Comment: ...all that being said... Canvas may be nice, but you're gonna have to deal with a plethora of other issues and you're at a much "lower level" in the graphics stack and much closer to Skia. You have over 600 "views" in your grid, why not use a standard viewHolder with a `ListAdapter<K, J>` and a `DiffUtil.Callback` to calculate changes? Have you explored that?

Comment: Is this open source? Is this code available online? If so, let us know.

Comment: True, it could be related to the Pixel class `onMeasure` implementation. I would try it using the View class directly and see how it looks. From OP's code, it's unclear if there are two different Pixel classes. The adapter takes a list of Pixels that have position properties, but a Pixel View class is shown. Wouldn't make sense to pass a list of Views to a RecylerView adapter.

Comment: Why pass a list of views? you pass a representation of `data class Pixel(val color: Color)`, each pixel position in a 2d space is irrelevant if it's a list with a hardcoded resolution (as it is) Pixel 0 is top left, pixel 24 is top right, pixel 25 is the 2nd row, left-most pixel. And so on and so forth. The grid would display them. A ViewHolder will _tint_ the color based on the data received.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini

Yes, it is open source: https://github.com/realtomjoney/PyxlMoose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you guys had mentioned in the comments, the custom View class called Pixel contains the code which makes sure the width and height are the same:

```
 override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec)

        val width = measuredWidth
        setMeasuredDimension(width, width)
    }
```

I think as you guys pointed out, removing this code fixed the problem for me.

Since the `onMeasure` function is removed, the class `Pixel` is redundant, so I will switch it to a regular `View` class in the future.

Right now it looks like so, as you can see, no slits are visible:

[image]

If anyone is facing a similar niche problem like this, I would recommend removing the 'onMeasure()' with the setMeasuredDimensions function (if you have one similar to mine), the RecyclerView automatically makes sure the width and height are equal so it's redundant and is the root of many problems.

If anyone wants to contribute to the code, as I had seen some of you request, here is the link:

https://github.com/realtomjoney/PyxlMoose

I think I will be sticking with RecyclerView for now, as I disagree with the notion that Canvas is easier, it actually seems to be the opposite of the case from the code I've seen. But thanks anyways.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a solution :) I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but here's how you could write a single View class that displays pixel art. Canvas is not very intimidating if you are only drawing rectangles.

This class doesn't enforce itself to be square, but you can do that using your layout constraints. If it's a view in a ConstraintLayout, you could use `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"` for this, or whatever ratio matches your ratio of horizontal and vertical pixel counts (if there isn't padding).

Drawing does create Set copies, but you could change it to using a MutableSet if performance is a problem. Or an alternate strategy could be to use a 2D array of Booleans (or Int colors) so you don't even need a Pixel class.

If you were going to support color, you could add a color property to the Pixel class and then you would change the color of the paint for each pixel inside the loop in `onDraw`.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Color
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.MotionEvent
import android.view.View

data class Pixel(val x: Int, val y: Int)

class PixelArtView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : View(context, attrs) {

    var pixels: Set<Pixel> = emptySet()
        set(value) {
            if (field != value) invalidate()
            field = value
        }

    var horizontalPixels: Int = 10
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    var verticalPixels: Int = 10
        set(value) {
            field = value
            invalidate()
        }

    private val pixelWidth: Float
        get() = (width - paddingLeft - paddingRight).toFloat() / horizontalPixels
    private val pixelHeight: Float
        get() = (height - paddingTop - paddingBottom).toFloat() / verticalPixels

    var isInteractive = true
    private var isErasing = false

    private val paint = Paint().apply {
        color = Color.BLACK
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    init {
        // So we can see something in the layout editor
        if (isInEditMode) pixels = List(10) { Pixel(it, it) }.toSet()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        val pixelWidth = pixelWidth
        val pixelHeight = pixelHeight
        for (pixel in pixels) {
            val left = paddingLeft + pixel.x * pixelWidth
            val top = paddingTop + pixel.y * pixelHeight
            canvas.drawRect(left, top, left + pixelWidth, top + pixelHeight, paint)
        }
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        if (isInteractive) {
            val touchDown = event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
            val touchMove = event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
            if (touchDown || touchMove) {
                val pixel = Pixel(
                    ((event.x - paddingLeft) / pixelWidth).toInt().coerceIn(0, horizontalPixels - 1),
                    ((event.y - paddingTop) / pixelHeight).toInt().coerceIn(0, verticalPixels - 1)
                )
                if (touchDown) {
                    isErasing = pixel in pixels
                }
                pixels = if (isErasing) pixels - pixel else pixels + pixel
                return true
            }
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your code and it looks as though it's well, but it seems as though your code is actually more complex and low-level than my implementation. In the future I may move to a Canvas but for now the app works fine as I have addressed the issue. The user can change the grid size, export their work to a png, so I don't really see a point of using a Canvas. Thanks though :)

Comment: Cool, have a look later when you're considering Canvas. Note that this class lets you click and drag your finger to draw and erase instead of having to tap each individual pixel. I just wanted to try writing it. It was the touch interaction that turned out to be truly low-level. The actual Canvas drawing is only seven lines of code. And all the calculations were simpler than this before I decided a proper view should support the View padding properties.

Comment: @Tenfour4 just wanted to share with you (update you on my progress), I found a way to get dragging functionality like you mentioned without the use of a Canvas! I even found a way to set the thickness of a brush also without using a Canvas. And it works amazingly :) My app has seen some major improvements since I posted this also with a ton of new features.

Comment: Cool, I’ll check out the code.

Comment: Looking back now, I think you were probably right, I'm trying to migrate my codebase to use a Canvas now as it's getting larger and some features can only be added with a Canvas.